# how to get the first level li listitem from list html using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

how to get the first level li listitem from list html using jquery ..for example I am working in draggable and sortable. I want to make each listitem draggable including---Sally and Bike ....Problem is when I select sally its children are also dragged.

```
<div id="content2">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>Some Text</p>
            <p>Some More Text</p>
            <div>Random Div</div>
            <ul>
                <li>Bob</li>
                <li>Sally
                    <ul>
                        <li>Car</li>
                        <li>Boat</li>
                        <li>Bike
                            <ul>
                                <li>Red</li>
                                <li>Green</li>
                                <li>Blue</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Larry</li>
                <li>Mo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *Problem is when I select sally its children are also dragged.* Can you explain your logic more here? What *should* happen when you drag **Sally**? I would expect the child elements to drag with the parent, no? Or, do you mean that the individual children are each made draggable and you only want the parent to be draggable?

Answer (score -1):

You dont show your jQuery (and you REALLY should) but I have feeling you are doing something like `$( "#content2 li" ).draggable();` which is applying the draggable feature to *all* of your `li`s and you want it to apply to only the top most `li`s.

To do that, I would give the `ul` a class like `target-ul` then select the `li`s that are direct children of that `ul` like `$( ".target-ul > li" ).draggable();`

```js
 $( function() {
    $( ".target-ul > li" ).draggable();
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<div id="content2">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>Some Text</p>
            <p>Some More Text</p>
            <div>Random Div</div>
            <ul class="target-ul">
                <li>Bob</li>
                <li>Sally
                    <ul>
                        <li>Car</li>
                        <li>Boat</li>
                        <li>Bike
                            <ul>
                                <li>Red</li>
                                <li>Green</li>
                                <li>Blue</li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Larry</li>
                <li>Mo</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```